# Not getting the value of File and metadata

Tags: visualforce, controller

This is my vf Page and I am not getting the value of file and metadata in Controller.

This is my Vf page

```
<apex:page docType="HTML-5.0" controller="AdminPannelController">
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.ColorPicker}" />
     <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Live Agent Configure ">
            <script>
                function saveData() {
                    var values = document.getElementById('valueInput').value
                    saveController(values);
                }

            </script>
            <apex:actionRegion >
                <apex:actionFunction action="{!save}" name="saveController" rerender="none">
                    <apex:param name="firstParam" value="" assignTo="{!colorCode}" />
                </apex:actionFunction>
            </apex:actionRegion>
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <apex:outputLabel value="BRAND :">
                            <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!metaData}">
                                <apex:selectOptions value="{!metaDataList}"></apex:selectOptions>
                            </apex:selectList>
                        </apex:outputLabel>
                        <apex:outputLabel value="BACK-GROUND COLOR:"> <button class="jscolor {valueElement:'valueInput',styleElement:'styleInput',value:'66ccff'}"
                                         style="width:50px; height:20px;"></button>

                           <input id="valueInput" value="{!colorCode}"/>
                        </apex:outputLabel>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <apex:outputLabel value="LOGO:">
                            <apex:inputFile value="{!file.body}" fileName="{!file.Name}"></apex:inputFile>
                        </apex:outputLabel>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <!--<apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!save}" /> -->


            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="Bottom">
                <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="saveData()"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

My controller

```
public with sharing class AdminPannelController

{   public Document file{get;set;}
    public string colorCode{get;set;}
    public string metaData{get;set;}
    public List<brand__mdt> BrandTypes = new List<brand__mdt>();

   public AdminPannelController(){
    file = new Document();
   }

   public List<SelectOption> metaDataList
   {
       get
       {
           BrandTypes = [Select DeveloperName From brand__mdt];

           metaDataList = new List<SelectOption>();

           for(brand__mdt types : BrandTypes)
           {
               metaDataList.add(new SelectOption(types.Id, types.DeveloperName));
           }
           return metaDataList;
       }
       set;
   }
   public pageReference save(){

       String temp = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('firstParam');
       System.debug('value input color code'+temp);

       Document Doc = new Document();
       System.debug('file '+file);
       Doc.name=File.Name;
       Doc.Body=File.Body;
       Doc.Folderid ='005d0000006TArF';
       insert Doc;

       AdminPanelBranding__c csetting = new AdminPanelBranding__c();
            csetting.Background_Color__c = temp;
            csetting.Logo__c = Doc.id;
            System.debug('Metadata name'+metaData);
            csetting.Name = metaData;

           List<AdminPanelBranding__c> existingCsetting = [Select Name from AdminPanelBranding__c where Name =: metaData limit 1];
            if(existingCsetting.size() == 0 ){
                insert csetting;
            }
            else{
                csetting = existingCsetting[0];
                update csetting;
            }

       pageReference pg = new pageReference('/'+ Doc.Id);
       pg.setRedirect(true);
       return pg;

   }
}
```

I am getting a error on clicking on after clicking on save button that Document name is required